# How can I use init state without using Provider and connect() in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

All:

I am pretty new to Redux, when I try to init state of the app, I want to directly give the `store.getState()` to `this.setState()` of the App component, but it keeps giving me some error like

> "Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)."

My code is like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'


var headerMenuReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "OPEN_MENU": {
            state.data.forEach(function(menu, i){
                if(menu.id == action.id ){
                    menu.active = true;
                } else {
                    menu.active = false;
                }
            })
            return state;
        }
        case "CLOSE_MENU": {
            state.data.forEach(function(menu, i){
                menu.active = false;
            })
            return state;
        }
        default: {
            return {
                data: [
                    {
                        type: "menu",
                        title: "Views",
                        id: "menu_views",
                        active: false
                    },
                    {
                        type: "menu",
                        title: "Portfolios",
                        id: "menu_portfolios",
                        active: false
                    },
                    {
                        type: "menu",
                        title: "Factors",
                        id: "menu_factors",
                        active: false

                    },
                    {
                        type: "menu",
                        title: "Tools",
                        id: "menu_tools",
                        active: false
                    },
                    {
                        type: "link",
                        title: "Information",
                        id: "menu_infomation",
                        active: true
                    }
                ]
            }// end of return
        }
    }
}

let store = createStore(headerMenuReducer);


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data:[]};
        this.style={
            "padding": "0 5px"
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState(store.getState());

    }
    activeMenu(id) {
        store.dispatch({
            type: "OPEN_MENU",
            id: id
        })
        this.setState( store.getState() )
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.data.map( (menu, i) => {
                        var style = Object.assign({}, this.style, {"backgroundColor": (menu.active?"lightblue": "lightpink")})
                        return <span key={menu.id} style={style} onClick={this.activeMenu(menu.id).bind(this)}>{menu.title}</span>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default App
```

Comment: this isn't how redux is intended to work. its how flux is though. you should consider either switching to flux and go about it this way. or pass props to the component that would be the same as state.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks, so this means I have to use `<Provider>` and `connect()`?

Comment: Yes you should be using connect to connect the component to your store. its the redux architechture. I'd recommend you read up a bit on redux and how its intended to work. :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks, I will do that. BTW, is my way to initialize the state data correct in reducer function?

Comment: http://codeloveandboards.com/blog/2015/10/16/react-state-management-fun-with-redux/ is a simple example but has some good info :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks, I will read that.

Comment: @JohnRuddell  Just want to share, #adamb  find the error, it is at my click handler, I accidentally specify it wrong, it should be like  `this.activeMenu.bind(this, menu.id)` but not `this.activeMenu(menu.id).bind(this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this component definition:

```
<span key={menu.id} style={style} onClick={this.activeMenu(menu.id).bind(this)}>{menu.title}</span>
```

You're *invoking* `activeMenu()` at *render* time. My guess is you'd like to invoke it at *click* time.

To do so I'd recommend making that `span` its own component, and invoking a passed prop callback internally within it -- passing the specific id accordingly.

**Something like this:**

```
const MenuButton = ({ id, title, onClick}) => (
    <span key={id} onClick={() => { onClick(id) }>{title}</span>
);

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        //...
    },
    activeMenu(id) {
        //...
    },
    render() {
        const menuButtons = this.state.data.map((menu, i) => {
            return <MenuButton id={menu.id} title={menu.title} onClick={this.activeMenu}>
        });

        return (
           <div>
               {menuButtons}
           </div>
        )
}
```

}

(Took out your style logic to make the example easier to follow.)

Comment: Thanks. So I should do something like `this.activeMenu.bind(this, menu.id)`, right? This is so stupid mistake....